# Prime Factorization Function Output

Tags: c++, function, prime-factoring

I made this function that calculates the prime factorization of a number (n) which is obtained from the user. I am having issues with it due to the fact that It does not print the same factor more than once.

For Example:

The Prime Factorization of 3960 is:

```
11 5 3 3 2 2 2
```

However my program only prints out:

```
11 5 3 2
```

Can anyone help me to identify the cause and help me find a solution?

```
void primefact(int n)
{ 
    Stack f;
    assert(n >= 0);
    bool prime;

    for(int d = 2; d <= n; d++) // Test for factors > 1
    {
        if(n % d == 0)
        {
            prime = true;
            for(int j = 2; j < d; j++) // Test for prime
            {
                if(d % j == 0) // It is not prime
                prime = false;
            }
            if(prime)
                f.push(d);
        }
    }

    while(!f.empty())
    {
        cout << f.top() << endl;
        f.pop();
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be a *stellar* time to walk through this code with a debugger.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simplest code for prime factorization:-

```
for ( int i = 2; i <= num; ++i )
{
    while ( num % i == 0 ) 
    {
        num /= i;
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution to the factorization problem, but doesn't directly address OP's question about why the code given doesn't work.

Comment: @NinjaZ: Sure it will.  Just do `f.push` instead of `cout <<`

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop over the same prime as long as it divides the input.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone help me to identify the cause?

You're checking whether `n` is divisible by `d`, but then you move on to the next value. If `n` is divisible by `d` and `d` is prime, you need to actually divide `n` by `d` and check `d` again.

Let's take 12 as an example. Prime factors are `[3, 2, 2]`. Your code does this:

```
n = 12, d = 2
n % d == 0? Yes. Push d. d = d + 1   
n % d == 0? Yes. Push d. d = d + 1
n % d == 0? No. d = d + 1
n % d == 0? No. d = d + 1
n % d == 0? No. d = d + 1
n % d == 0? No. d = d + 1
// and so on until d == n
```

You want code that does this:

```
n = 12, d = 2
n % d == 0? Yes. Push d. n = n/d      // n is 6, d is 2
n % d == 0? Yes. Push d. n = n/d      // n is 3, d is 2
n % d == 0? No. d = d + 1             // n is 3, d is 3
n % d == 0? Yes. Push d. n = n/d      // n is 1 so you're done
```

Comment: So, the cause of the problem is that you're just checking each number to see *if* it's a prime factor, right? But each time you find a prime factor, you want to divide `n` by that factor and then try the same factor again. Short of writing the code for you, I'm not sure how to explain the issue better than that.

Answer (score 0):

You probably know yourself that your algorithm is far from optimal. So this won't hurt the performance much. Replace

```
if(prime)
    f.push(d);
```

with

```
if (prime)
{
    for (int d1 = d; n % d1 == 0; d1 *= d)
        f.push(d);
}
```